# Рандомный выбор элементов массива

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Есть код:

```
<script>
    var a = new Array
     a= [1,2,3,4,5];
</script>
<a id="link">click</a>
```

Как при клике на ссылку организовать рандомный вывод элеметов массива, ну, скажем, через alert?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j4mz2x9o/ - клик попробуйте реализовать сами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оптимальным решением будет перемешать массив в случайном порядке, а уже потом выбирать из него элементы.

[Проверяйте](http://jsfiddle.net/codLvLhr/)